# Azure Mobile App - upload image and process it in the backend

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-mobile-services

I am following [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-universal-dotnet-upload-data-blob-storage/) and I got it working when I tried about 6 months ago. Now I am creating a new project using Azure Mobile Apps. Is this still the same?
And now I have new requirement. This is for college task and I need to process the image that I upload to convert it to grayscale and resize it on the server.
How can I do this in Azure?
I know I can easily process the image in client but the new requirement that the image must be processed on the server.
My data object looks like this:

```
public class Photo : EntityData
    {
        public string ContainerName { get; set; }

        public string ResourceName { get; set; }

        public string SasQueryString { get; set; }

        public string ImageUri { get; set; }

        public string Caption { get; set; }

        public string Base64Image { get; set; }
    }
```

I have an idea to convert it to Base64 string. But looks like I can't get bitmap/Image from azure .NET backend app

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be for you to follow the C# version of the tutorial you linked to to first upload the original image from the client using the SAS token mechanism in that tutorial. You could then make a second request from your client to process the image - this second request would simply be a POST to a custom API that receives the image URI. In the backend you can then use the Azure Storage SDK to read the image from blob, process it, and store the new image either at the same location, or as a new image. This API then returns the URI of the final image back to the client.

A second approach that is a little more sophisticated would be to use a **WebJob** for your image processing as described in [this post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/). Going this route, your client would upload the original image as before, and the WebJob would process the image asynchronously and update storage with the new image as well as updating the Photo DB record with the possibly new image URI when it completes. In this approach, there might be a couple second delay before that image is fully processed and the Photo record is updated, so it really depends on your app scenario. An approach like this might scale better though, particularly if your image processing takes a while.